# Android upload on aws s3 http

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, upload

I have this problem in the onError of the upload: Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0x7b4a65b280: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

I don't know why, also I've followed the guidelines.

I have `<service android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService" android:enabled="true" />` in the manifest

I Have `implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'` in the internal gradle

My code:

```
public void upload(String path,File file) {
    path=path.replace("/storage/emulated/0/blablabla/","");
    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "blablabla", // Identity pool ID
            Regions.EU_WEST_1 // Region
    );
    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());
    final TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
            "blablabla",  //this is the bucket name on S3
            path, //this is the path and name
            file //path to the file locally
    );
    observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            if (state.equals(TransferState.COMPLETED)) {
                Log.d("AMAZON","si");
            } else if (state.equals(TransferState.FAILED)) {
                //Failed
                Log.d("AMAZON","no");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            Log.d("AMAZON",ex.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on a really antiquated version of the SDK. Please upgrade to the latest version 2.16.6 and try uploading using the instruction here : 
https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/sdk/android/storage#upload-a-file

Comment: 8 month have passed from this question.

Comment: I saw that and I realize this might not even be relevant now but since this did not have an answer I decided post something relevant. Lot have changed in past 8 months but you version "2.2" was old even 8 months ago :)